# UIViewController - mysteriously slow to load

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm writing a tab-based universal app where one of the tabs takes considerably much longer to load than the rest (approximately 5s), and it locks down the main thread while doing it.

Now, this specific tab is an image gallery, so it could be expected to take a little while to load and display the images, however, the delay occurs *before* I instantiate any of my variables... (The image loading is done on a separate thread anyway...)

I create my subviews etc. in the `viewDidLoad` method, but the delay occurs somewhere after the init method and before the `viewDidLoad` method.

*(The delay is present even if I comment out everything in the `viewDidLoad` method.)*

The View Controller is initialized with a nib containing nothing but a `UIScrollView` and a `UIImagePickerController`...

Does anyone know what's being loaded/processed before the `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: viewDidLoad will not be fired until you reference the view property of the view controller from somewhere, for example in an addSubView call. Make sure you are referencing the view as soon as you initialise the controller.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a problem with loading UIImagePickerController on the phone while being attached to the xcode harness. This creates a longer than normal delay. Try testing on the device without being connected to the xcode debugger.

Comment: That's it! Finding non-existant issues in the code is always the hardest... Thanks a million!