# Load UIImagePickerController faster?

Tags: ios, multithreading, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I need to load `UIImagePickerController` faster. My app will call `UIImagePickerController` from possibly multiple controllers and within each controller there are two buttons, one for Photo Library, another for Camera. This is my sample app. Some solutions I tried are recommended by Apple in '**Concurrency Programming Guide**'. 
The simplest is to alloc & init an instance when user presses a button. This can take up to 2 seconds before the camera shows up. 
Solution attempt:-
 (1) I made a @property (...) *imagePicker and called its alloc & init in `viewDidAppear` to make it seem smooth, but it interfered with loading of other elements, possibly because it was using the same thread. Worse results when used in `initWithNibName` or `viewDidLoad`. 
(2) `Operation queues`... not pleasing results. 
(3) `Dispatch Queues`... better results but still noticeable choppy performance. 
(4) `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` not great results. I don't think I want to go global, unless otherwise recommended. I have no problem making two @properties of `UIImagePickerController`. I will continue to possibly '**Threading Programming Guide**'. 
Please include any necessary memory management practices with your solutions, if you can. Thank you.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
// (1) TRYING OPERATION QUEUES
    // (a) --- NSBlockOperation
    NSBlockOperation *NSBO_IP = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSLog(@"before");
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        // 1.9, 1.6, 1.4 seconds pass between 'before' and 'after'
        // it seems this method has a dynamic technique, executes in different order every time
        NSLog(@"after");
    }];
    // (b) --- NSInvocationOperation
    NSInvocationOperation *NSIO_IP = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadTheImagePicker) object:nil];
    // --- Add an operation
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    //NSLog(@"time 1");
    // (a) [queue addOperation:NSBO_IP];
    // (b) [queue addOperation:NSIO_IP];
    //NSLog(@"time 2");
// (2)TRYING DISPATCH QUEUES
    // (a) --- GCD call  (do I need to release 'myQueue' at some point since this is C-level call?)
/*
    NSLog(@"time 1");
    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        // 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.4 seconds significant increase over Operation Queues
        // a solid constant executing technique, executes very consistently
    });
    NSLog(@"time 2");
*/
// (3)TRYING performSelectorInBackground:withObject  (not recommended?)
    NSLog(@"time 1");
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadTheImagePicker) withObject:nil];
    // 1.3, 1.7, 1.3 seconds pass between 'before' and 'after'
    NSLog(@"time 2");
// RESULTS REFLECTED IN LINE BELOW !
    [self changeText:self];  // text does not change on time when trying to alloc & init an ImagePickerController
}
    - (void)loadTheImagePicker
    {
    NSLog(@"before");
    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    // --- NSInvocationOperation used
    // 1.6, 1.2, 1.4 seconds pass between 'before' and 'after'
    // this method has a more constant executing technique, as far as order of executions
    // --- NSInvocationOperation used
    NSLog(@"after");
}
```

Comment: It's not recommended to perform UI changes on a background thread, it becomes unpredictable. So have you tried without any thread at all?

Comment: normally, the view will be loaded _after_ the `UIViewController` is added to the navigation stack (this or that way). I would **not** recommend that but you can call the `–loadView` method _before_ it will be added; it saves you a little time, but the behaviour is undefined of calling the `–loadView` method like this, so that would be a definite risk. NB: _initialising_ a view is not equal to _loading_ a view (and its components).

Comment: Yes, Emanuel, I have tried without any thread at all. It takes the longest time to load.

Comment: holex, even if the initializing is different than loading a view and/or its components, the [[… alloc] init] has to finish executing before [[theScrollView] subviews] array is populated with my images, in my actual App. I moved away from initializing it when the user presses a camera button, but now anywhere I place it, it carries with it a no less than 1.2 second execution time the execution of it's neighboring methods. I will definitely find a solution and post it when I'm done, thanks

Comment: I found the solution. This question has already been answered. It seems when connected to Xcode debugger the [UIImagePickerController alloc] init] takes much longer to execute than when running the App without Xcode. My solution is still to keep @property and do the alloc & init in the viewDidLoad method. The other solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230907/uiviewcontroller-mysteriously-slow-to-load

Answer (score 5):

from @Murat's answer in a comment:

> I found the solution. This question has already been answered. It
>   seems when connected to Xcode debugger the `[UIImagePickerController
>   alloc] init]` takes much longer to execute than when running the App
>   without Xcode.
>
> My solution is still to keep `@property` and do the `alloc`
>   & `init` in the `viewDidLoad` method.
>
> The other solution is here:
>   [UIViewController - mysteriously slow to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230907/uiviewcontroller-mysteriously-slow-to-load)

moved this to an answer as I almost missed it as a comment.