# UIActionSheet delay after user has selected option?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

I create a `UIActionSheet` by:

```
 [vActionSheet showC:@"Change Profile Picture"
                 cancel:@"Cancel"
                buttons:@[@"Take Photo", @"Choose from Library"]
                 result:^(int nResult) {

                     if (nResult == 0 || nResult == 1)
                     {
                         self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                         self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
                         self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;

                         if (nResult == 0)
                         {
                             self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                         }
                         else if (nResult == 1)
                         {
                             self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                         }

                         [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];

                     }

                 }];
```

But when I launch my app, and I select "Choose from Library" for example, the first time that I do this running my app, it takes about 2-3 seconds for the Photo Library to present itself, however if i go back, by selecting "Cancel" on the photo library or camera, and bring my my `UIActionSheet` again, select the same option as before, say the library it pops up right away the way it normally should thats the behavior that is expected, you tap it and right away it should come up, what could be the reason that the first time it doesn't do it like that, and in fact takes a noticeable 2-3 second pause prior to presenting? What can I do to fix this problem?

**UPDATE**: I don't think the issue has to do with the size of the library, because for this test my photo library only contains one photo. Additionally, If I try to perform the same task with an application like Instagram, this delay does not occur.

Comment: Could it be that UIImagePickerController takes some time to initialize the first time it is called in your app? How big is the photo library on your device?

Comment: @BrianWalker, well i don't think that is the case, if I perform the same action with Instagram, it pops up right away. I only have 1 image in my library for testing purposes.

Comment: Are you seeing this when running the app from Xcode when the device is connected to your dev machine? What happens if you unplug the device  from the computer and run the app (so it is not running with the debugger)?

Comment: Found some duplicate questions [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230907/uiviewcontroller-mysteriously-slow-to-load) and [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753151/load-uiimagepickercontroller-faster). They both mention the picker is slow to load when running under Xcode.

Comment: @BrianWalker disconnecting my device did the trick for me, I saw that was also the answer on the other questions thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem seems to be related to Xcode in one way or another, with the device unplugged the `UIActionSheet` runs just fine.